# How to send php GET request to google contacts api v3 OAuth2

Tags: php, curl, gdata, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

### Problem Solved

I have successfully obtained an OAuth2 token with proper scopes for accessing Google Calendar Events and Google Contacts (*-edit-* with both APIs enabled on Google Developers console), using the php client library. I am able to access events with the client using the service however there is no service for contacts.

How can I manually send an authorized GET request to the Google Contacts API (GData-ver:3.0) with the OAuth2 token [as referenced here?](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)

This is in Joomla 3.x but I'm working directly with php.

```
$retrieveURL = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=' . urlencode($tokens->access_token) . '&v=3.0';
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $retrieveURL);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$gContacts = curl_exec($cURL);
if ($errno = curl_errno($cURL)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo("cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}:\n ");
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
}
var_dump($gContacts);
return $gContacts;
```

The response from Google:

```
401. That's an error. There was an error in your request. That's all we know.
```

Comment: Is Contacts API enabled for your application in Google Developers Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using `Google_Http_Request` object from the PHP client library.

```
  $retrieveURL = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json';

  $httpRequest = new Google_Http_Request($retrieveURL, 'GET');

  /** 
   * this will first check and renew access_token if needed 
   * then sets the access token in the request header 
   **/
  $client->getAuth()->sign($httpRequest);

  /**
   * modify the request to work with Google Contacts API v3.0
   **/
  $httpRequest->setBaseComponent('https://www.google.com');
  $httpRequest->setRequestHeaders(['Gdata-version' => '3.0']));

  /**
   * Send the request and assign the response
   **/
  $response = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($httpRequest);

  // replace problematic '$'s with 'G's in json response string
  $responseString = implode('G', explode('$', $response->getResponseBody()));
  $responseBody = json_decode($responseString);
  $responseArray = $responseBody->feed->entry;

  foreach ((array)$responseArray as $entry) {
    $gdName = (isset($entry->gdGname->gdGfullName->Gt)) ? $entry->gdGname->gdGfullName->Gt : 'No Name';
    $gdFName = (isset($entry->gdGname->gdGgivenName->Gt)) ? $entry->gdGname->gdGgivenName->Gt : 'No First Name';
    $gdLName = (isset($entry->gdGname->gdGfamilyName->Gt)) ? $entry->gdGname->gdGfamilyName->Gt : 'No Last Name';
    $gdEmail = (isset($entry->gdGemail[0]->address)) ? $entry->gdGemail[0]->address : 'No Email Address';
    $gdPhone = (isset($entry->gdGphoneNumber[0]->Gt)) ? $entry->gdGphoneNumber[0]->Gt : 'No Phone Number';
    $gdOrgName = (isset($entry->gdGorganization[0]->gdGorgName->Gt)) ? $entry->gdGorganization[0]->gdGorgName->Gt : 'No Company Name';
    $output[] = [
      "name"       => $gdName,
      "first_name" => $gdFName,
      "last_name"  => $gdLName,
      "email"      => $gdEmail,
      "phone"      => $gdPhone,
      "company"    => $gdOrgName,
    ];
  }

  $app = $this->app;

  // store the contact and redirect to view
  $_SESSION["gdContacts"] = $output;
  $app->redirect(JRoute::_('web/content/google/contacts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Access token cannot be used as a parameter on your http GET request. You need to set them up in your web application. How to do that can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#callinganapi).

GET request of `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0` should be able to work once the set up is done

Comment: That uses the service object for the api, and there is no Contacts service. I have tried using an authenticated client that works with the calendar service, and tried using its available methods to send the request with varied levels of failure. I need to know what the service does/would do to send a request, that's why I asked how to manually send an authorized request.